# Close Fancybox, sumbit form data and redirect

Tags: jquery, plugins, javascript

I have a Wordpress and WooCommerce site for a client, and to create a little twist on the customizing on a product I have a external html-page opening in a FancyBox iFrame using Easy FancyBox plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/).

Now when the user is done with the form inside that iframe, which sends data using GET to the checkout form, I want the FancyBox to close and move the user to the cart/checkout page.

At least close the box and reload the page so that I can show the user a message that the product was added.

How would I do that? I'm rather new to this kind of stuff.

Do I need to ad some kind of jQuery/JavaScript to a file and then call it somehow from the submit button?

Comment: check this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3660710/712612

Comment: Thank you, but this is for a <a> and I have a form submit button. Trying to merge them.

Answer (score 2):

So this is what I did to make it work:

```
<form id="formid" name="form" action="/checkout" method="get">
    Text: <input type="text" name="text"><br>
    <a href="/checkout" target="_parent" onclick="document.getElementById('formid').submit();">Finish</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="mess" value=Finish />
</form>
```